# How to properly fread & fwrite from & to a pipe

Tags: c, linux, pipe, eof, stdio

I have this code which acts as a pipe between two shell invocations.

It reads from a pipe, and writes into a different one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define BUFF_SIZE (0xFFF)

/*
 *  $ cat /tmp/redirect.txt |less
 */
int main(void)
{
    FILE    *input;
    FILE    *output;
    int     c;
    char    buff[BUFF_SIZE];
    size_t  nmemb;

    input   = popen("cat /tmp/redirect.txt", "r");
    output  = popen("less", "w");
    if (!input || !output)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

#if 01
    while ((c = fgetc(input))  !=  EOF)
        fputc(c, output);
#elif 01
    do {
        nmemb   = fread(buff, 1, sizeof(buff), input);
        fwrite(buff, 1, nmemb, output);
    } while (nmemb);
#elif 01
    while (feof(input) != EOF) {
        nmemb   = fread(buff, 1, sizeof(buff), input);
        fwrite(buff, 1, nmemb, output);
    }
#endif
/*
 * EDIT: The previous implementation is incorrect:
 * feof() return non-zero if EOF is set
 * EDIT2:  Forgot the !.  This solved the problem.
 */
#elif 01
    while (feof(input)) {
        nmemb   = fread(buff, 1, sizeof(buff), input);
        fwrite(buff, 1, nmemb, output);
    }
#endif

    pclose(input);
    pclose(output);

    return  0;
}
```

I want it to be efficient, so I want to implement it with `fread()`&`fwrite()`.  There are the 3 way I tried.

The first one is implemented with `fgetc()`&`fputc()` so it will be very slow.  However it works fine because it checks for `EOF` so it will wait until `cat` (or any shell invocation I use) finishes its job.

The second one is faster, but I'm concerned that I don't check for `EOF` so if there is any moment when the pipe is empty (but the shell invocation hasn't finished, so may not be empty in the future), it will close the pipe and end.

The third implementation is what I would like to do, and it relatively works (all the text is received by `less`), but for some reason it gets stuck and doesn't close the pipe (seems like it never gets the EOF).

**EDIT:** Third implementation is buggy.  Fourth tries to solve the bug, but now `less` doesn't receive anything.

How should this be properly done?

Comment: `cat` is not a system call.

Comment: `while (feof)` is always wrong. And the usage of `feof()` function is also wrong, it doesn't return EOF. The second one checks for EOF, if the stream is not O_NONBLOCK, the `read` will return 0 only in case of EOF. The fastest would be to alllocate 4K buffer and write and read using that buffer. Reading and writing with one char is inefficient . If you want do one char at a time, use `fgetc` and `fputc`.

Comment: have you tried `select()` and add check for `stdin`..http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html

Comment: `fread` will block until either all the data you requested is available, all the write ends of the pipe are closed (eg, the program writing to the other end of the pipe terminates), or an error occurs.

Comment: @WilliamPursell fixed that wording.

Comment: The other option is `fgets` with `fputs` which will copy a line at a time.

Comment: Maybe related: [reddit why is GNU `yes` so fast](https://www.reddit.com/r/unix/comments/6gxduc/how_is_gnu_yes_so_fast/)

Comment: @KamilCuk @WilliamPursell Forgot the `!` in `while(!feof)`.  So pipes are infinite buffers? The program will have already finished by the time I read, and I will have a buffer to read from it as long as the output of the program?  Are you implying that implementation 2 is correct?

Comment: The [`while(feof)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong) is still conceptually always wrong. It just happens to work here, because `fwrite` with zero characters is just a no-op. The proper usage of `feof` would be right after you do a operation on the stream, like `while (1) { count = fread(...); if (feof(...)) break; fwrite(...); }`

Comment: `pipes are infinite buffers? ` Pipes in linux usually have 4K buffer, that's why it's best to disable line buffering on them and use a 4K buffer for I/O operations. | `he program will have already finished` = No. The program runs concurrent to yours. If the pipes buffer is full, and the program calls `write(STDOUT_FILENO` the call will block the program until you read from the buffer

Comment: @KamilCuk Ok, now I get how it works (I think) :)  So every `fread()` asks the called program to output another `BUFF_SIZE` characters, and after that, the program will pause until I ask for more?  So the result will be in no characters being lost because one program runs faster than the other.

Comment: `FILE*` is a _big_ abstraction, but let's take it. If a `FILE*` is opened on a file descriptor that doesn't has the `O_NONBLOCK` flag set, then if you do `fread(buff, sizeof(buff), 1,  in);` then it will return `0` or `sizeof(buff)`. If you call `fread(buff, 1, sizeof(buff), in)` then you can get a partial read - it can return any number between `0` and `sizeof(buff)`.

Comment: @KamilCuk Of course I mean `BUFF_SIZE` as an upper limit, if the called program has fewer bytes to output then I will get less. But will it always block until either I have something to read, or the called program finished? And the called program will always pause when the buffer is full?  Assuming `0_NONBLOCK`isn't set.

Comment: Yes. It will block, until it receives it all the required data (in `size` blocks) or EOF.

Comment: @KamilCuk, why do you think 4Kb buffer is the best and not the one used internally by `stdio`? (that is supposed to know the filesystem details better than you, and is portable, as in each system you don't have to say about those 4Kb to become more or less)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, to say that I think you are having problems more with buffering, than with efficiency.  That is a common problem when first dealing with the `stdio` package.

Second, the best (and simplest) implementation of a simple data copier from input to output is the following snippet (copied from K&R first ed.).

```
while((c = fgetc(input)) != EOF) 
    fputc(c, output);
```

(well, not a literal copy, as there, K&R use `stdin` and `stdout` as `FILE*` descriptors, and they use the simpler `getchar();` and `putchar(c);` calls.)  When you try to do better than this, normally you incur in some false assumptions, as the fallacy of the lack of buffering or the number of system calls.

**`stdio` does full buffering when the standard output is a pipe** (indeed, it does full buffering always except when the file descriptor gives `true` to the `isatty(3)` function call), so you should do, in the case you want to see the output as soon as it is available, at least, no output buffering (with something like `setbuf(out, NULL);`, or `fflush()`) your output at some point, so it doesn't get buffered in the output while you are waiting in the input for more data.

What it seems to be is that you see that the output for the `less(1)` program is not visible, because it is being buffered in the internals of your program.  And that is exactly what is happening... suppose you feed your program (which, despite of the handling of individual characters, is doing full buffering) doesn't get any input until the full input buffer (`BUFSIZ` characters) have been feeded to it.  Then, a lot of single `fgetc()` calls are done in a loop, with a lot of `fputc()` calls are done in a loop (exactly `BUFSIZ` calls each) and the buffer is filled at the output.  But this buffer is not written, because it need one more char to force a flush.  So, until you get the first two `BUFSIZ` chunks of data, you don't get anything written to `less(1)`.

A simple, and efficient way is to check after `fputc(c, out);` if the char is a `\n`, and flush output with `fflush(out);` in that case, and so you'll write a line of output at a time.

```
fputc(c, out);
if (c == '\n') fflush(out);
```

If you don't do something, the buffering is made in `BUFSIZ` chunks, and normally, not before you have such an amount of data in the output side. And remember always to `fclose()` things (well, this is handled by `stdio`), or you can lose output in case your process gets interrupted.

IMHO the code you should use is:

```
while ((c = fgetc(input))  !=  EOF) {
    fputc(c, output);
    if (c == '\n') fflush(output);
}
fclose(input);
fclose(output);
```

for the best performance, while not blocking unnecessarily the output data in the buffer.

BTW, doing `fread()` and `fwrite()` of one char, is a waste of time and a way to complicate things a lot (and error prone). `fwrite()` of one char will not avoid the use of buffers, so you won't get more performance than using `fputc(c, output);`.

BTW(bis) if you want to do your own buffering, don't call `stdio` functions, just use `read(2)` and `write(2)` calls on normal system file descriptors.  A good approach is:

```
int input_fd = fileno(input); /* input is your old FILE * given by popen() */
int output_fd = fileno(output);

while ((n = read(input_fd, your_buffer, sizeof your_buffer)) > 0) {
    write(output_fd, your_buffer, n);
}
switch (n) {
case 0: /* we got EOF */
    ...
    break;
default: /* we got an error */
    fprintf(stderr, "error: read(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
    ...
    break;
} /* switch */
```

but this will awaken your program only when the buffer is fully filled with data, or there's no more data.

If you want to feed your data to `less(1)` as soon as you have one line for less, then you can disable completely the input buffer with:

```
setbuf(input, NULL);
int c; /* int, never char, see manual page */
while((c == fgetc(input)) != EOF) {
    putc(c, output);
    if (c == '\n') fflush(output);
}
```

And you'll get `less(1)` working as soon as you have produced a single line of output text.

What are you exactly trying to do? (This would be nice to know, as you seem to be reinventing the `cat(1)` program, but with reduced functionality)

Comment: For sending efficiently each line, could I use `fgets()` and `fputs()` instead, and `fflush()` after each iteration (similarly to your last snippet)?  If so, could you add it to your answer?

Comment: that's not a good idea, because it ties your program to the maximum line size you have defined.... I don't recommend doing that.  You need to know what will happen if you receive lines longer than the buffer size you have selected.  Believe me, the first sample I wrote has survived about 50 years right now.

Comment: `fputs()` uses buffering also, so it will hold the output because you are dealing with a fifo, and not with a tty.  If you check the number of times each character is copied, you'll see that both solutions are similar.

Comment: Then your last snippet seems to be perfect.

Comment: I beg to differ:it is (performancewise) sub-optimal. more than half of  the CPU cycles will be spent on the function call overhead. Just benchmark the stuff and compare system time <--> usertime. Just get rid of all  these function calls.

Comment: @wildplasser, sometimes you have to sacrifice performance with a clear notation.  Normally, where you spend all the time is in the readin/writting of the fifos.  In this case we can go from (O(n) --> O(2n)) but you have not considered that copying to a local buffer also implies a loop, and then copy back to the output buffer does the same (so we are also in O(2n) already).  Obviously, if you do nothing than copy, all the time will be spent there. What's the difference between copying a bunch of chars one by one, or doing them calling a routine (that finally does this copying them one by one) ?

Comment: @wildplasser, and the difference between calling the function or expand the macro belongs to the case you include or not the `<stdio.h>` header file, which is something buried depth in the legacy.  Of course that using a function to copy a char is more expensive than doing with only one instruction.  But that happens automatically when you `#include <stdio.h>`, so it's not an issue here.  I think today nobody even thinks of using stdio package without including its header file, so your point in the discussion is clearly out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution:

---

```
while (1) {
    nmemb = fread(buff, 1, sizeof buff, input);
    if (nmemb < 1) break; 
    fwrite(buff, 1, nmemb, output);
}
```

---

Similarly, for the `getc()` case:

---

```
while (1) {
    c = getc(input);
    if (c == EOF) break;
    putc(c, output);
}
```

---

Replacing `fgetc()` by `getc()` will give performance equivalent to the `fread()`case. (`getc()` will (often) be a macro, avoiding function-call overhead). [just take a look at the generated assembly.

Comment: `nmemb` is unsigned (`size_t`).  Why check `<1`?  Just `!` will do.

Comment: As the link @KamilCuk posted in a comment to the question proves, buffering can improve speed a lot.

Comment: WRT `(nmemb<1)`: you  are right. (But it won't harm) WRT buffering: In either case, the FILE is  buffered. (check the assembly!)

Comment: Without `-O3` I have very different assembly code.  With `-O3`, `getc`&`putc` are optimized to `fread`&`fwrite`.  GCC 8 @ Debian

Comment: `getc()` is normally the same as `fgetc(stdin)`, so you don't always get that performance.  The macro issue affects calling a `getc()` version of the function just to make a second call to `fgetc(stdin)`.

Comment: One advice: do the math. (or: measure) I rest mycase.